# Compute the sum of all numbers in a string

Tags: c++

I'm working on this program, it asked me to compute the sum of all numbers in a string. For example:

```
Input: There are 10 chairs, 4 desks, and 2 fans.  
Output: 16  
Explanation: 10 + 4 + 2 = 16
```

My program is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "There are 10 chairs, 4 desks, and 2 fans.";
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] >= 0 && str[i] <= 9)
            sum += (int)str[i];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

I don't understand why the output of my program is `0`, can someone explain what's wrong with my program. Thank you

Comment: Note: There's no encoding where e.g. `0 == '0'`. Also, with your attempt you treat e.g. `10` as the distinct numbers `1` and `0` which would give you the sum `1` and not `10`.

Comment: ASCII code for digits are numbers [48, 57];

Comment: As for a possible way to solve your problem: Put the string into an input string stream. Read word by word from this stream, into a string. Try to convert the word to a number. If successful add to the sum. If you need to save the numbers to display later (in your "explanation") then push all numbers into a vector.

Comment: Change `if(str[i] >= 0 && str[i] <= 9)` to `if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')` and `sum += (int)str[i];` to `sum += str[i] - '0';`. This won't give you the correct answer, but at least you might understand the difference between `int` and `char`.

Comment: @pptaszni, how can you memorize the entire ASCII table ?

Comment: @john, why do you have to minus `'0'` ?

Comment: Because `str[i]` is a `char` not an `int`. Subtracting `'0'` converts the digit into the corresponding integer value. Try this code `cout << (int)'0' << ' ' << (int)'1' << ' ' << (int)'2';` to better understand what is going on.

Comment: @john, Ok I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @abcd But in any case your approach is wrong. Even with my changes the output will be `7` because `1+0+4+2` is `7`. You have to be a bit smarter. Some programmer dude in his comment explains what you actually need to do.

Comment: @pptaszni There are other encodings than ASCII, where the digits will not have the same numbers. Better use the actual literal characters like `'0'` etc. Or even better yet use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Comment: In your case, you want to search for [patterns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). Something like `[0-9]+` should do the trick. This will match the numbers in their entirety and not add just the individual numbers which won't have the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ascii](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp#:%7E:text=The%20ASCII%20Character%20Set&text=ASCII%20is%20a%207%2Dbit,are%20all%20based%20on%20ASCII.) code to find the numbers in `string`. the **0** `ascii` code is **48** and **9** is **57**. after find the number in `string`  you should make whole number for example **10** is **1** and **0**. and you should make `string` with value **"10"** and use `stoi` to convert it to `int`.

```
  int main()
    {
        string str = "There are 10 chairs, 4 desks, and 2 fans.";
        int sum = 0;
        string number;
        bool new_number = false , is_number ;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        {
            // if you use ascii it is good. 
           //but if you use other character encodings.you should use if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
            if (str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57)
            {
                number += str[i];
                if (!(str[i+1] >= 48 && str[i+1] <= 57))
                {
                    
                        sum += stoi(number);
                        number = "";
                }
            }
           
          
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
```

Comment: There really is no benefit in using numbers like `48` and `57` which  are only correct for ASCII. Just use `'0'` and `'9'` which are correct for all character encodings.

Comment: Also your code only works for two digit numbers. It would fail for a three digit number.

Comment: @john the `stoi` run when the next character is not a number.  so the code works well.

Comment: Well I don't agree with using ASCII, but I did misunderstand the code so I've removed my down vote. My apologies.

Comment: @Jarod42 do you mean that if put the number at the end of string make problem?? I put some number at the end of string and the code worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use regex, because everyone **loves** regex.

```
int main() {
  std::string str = "There are 10 chairs, 4 desks, and 2 fans.";

  std::regex number_regex("(\\d+)");

  auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), number_regex);
  auto end   = std::sregex_iterator();

  int sum = 0;
  for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
    auto m = *i;
    sum += std::stoi(m.str());
  }

  std::cout << sum << "\n";
}
```